# How can I get all roster name with presence in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am creating a chat application in iPhone, I want to display the roster's with current presence, but i got all roster's ID.

```
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];

if (queryElement) {
    NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
    [cts removeAllObjects];
    for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++) {

        NSString *jid = [[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
        [cts addObject:jid];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Roster ID's %@",cts);
```

this is the code for i am getting all rosters id's, i want to get presence and status and etc.,

How can I get Please Help Me.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: posting some code would be useful if you would like people to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one of best xmpp framework for iOS I found and its working perfectly. [XMPPFramwork from Robbiehnson](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

Comment: under  `- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence`  you will be able to get status like this   `NSString *statusMsg = [[presence elementForName:@"status"] stringValue];`

Comment: refer [rfc3921#presence](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#presence) to get the idea about presence